# Emacs sr-speedbar

Tags: emacs, editor

I am currently trying to learn Emacs more in depth so that I can do more with my Emacs than just simple editing stuff...
I am making good progress and at the moment I am trying to configure the 'sr-speedbar' module to my liking, but some details I can't figure out myself:

- Say that I've 2 open buffer windows A and B plus the speedbar window. If I open a file by pressing Enter in the speedbar window, then the new file always get opened in the same buffer window B (which I opened last). Can I somehow specify that the new content should be opened in buffer window A?
- Currently the speedbar window refreshes itself automatically to the new location whenever I open a new file using 'C-x C-f'. This is actually pretty useful, but sometimes I don't want this when I am quickly trying things out in a tmp file. And the refresh also "destroys" my "tree-view" of the speedbar, where I expanded the directory contents rather than opening them directly. The question is, how can I suppress this "refreshing behaviour"? Can I somehow disable the automatic mode and trigger it manually if I need it?

And do you guys have more useful tips regarding speedbar navigation? How does a Emacs guru use speedbar or are there better alternatives?

Thx in advance for your help!

Comment: I can only point you to a decent list of alternatives: http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Speed_bar#See_also I think Emacs gurus tend not to use a speed bar but prefer quick file navigation with a project explorer (`helm-projectile`), code source navigation (`imenu` and the like) and use Dired when needed. I may be missing out a use case.

Comment: @Ehvince thx for the list. I'll definitely look into it. But I've now found the `project-explorer` package, which seems to be exactly what I am looking for...

Comment: Cool. It's the second element of the list :) Don't hesitate to write more about it in the wiki :)

Answer (score 10):

You can turn off the auto-refresh in your init file like this -

```
(require 'sr-speedbar)
(setq sr-speedbar-auto-refresh nil)
```

and/or turn it on and off later with the function `sr-speedbar-refresh-toggle`.

The defaults it (and speedbar) comes with are a bit odd though - it also doesn't show files that it doesn't recognize, uses images for buttons, and is set on the right side - so you can set these if you'd like -

```
(setq speedbar-show-unknown-files t) ; show all files
(setq speedbar-use-images nil) ; use text for buttons
(setq sr-speedbar-right-side nil) ; put on left side
```

I do use sr-speedbar for projects that have enough of a directory structure - otherwise I use the usual switch-to-buffer (C-x b), ibuffer (C-x C-b), and dired (C-x d), and another function that switches to the previous buffer. Also bound to single keys because they get used so much.

But... I'm still learning Emacs - I haven't tried helm, projectile, or project-explorer yet - they look interesting also.